# How to Animate Position in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

I was trying to animate an html object to move from one position to another using css and I'm running into some strange issues. Whenever I implement the animation the object disappears. I also was working with an animation that fades a shadow in and out and that one works fine so I'm not sure what the issue is. Tried running in both Chrome and Safari, and including the webkit animation command just to make sure it wasn't the issue, which it shouldn't be because the fade ran fine without it. Let me know if you see what's wrong thanks!

CSS:

```
body{
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

#fall{position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: -1;}

#c1{position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; border-radius: 50%; width: 10px; height: 10px; z-index: 10; 
    animation: fall 3s ease infinite; -webkit-animation: fall 3s ease infinite; background-color: white;
}

@keyframes swell{
    from {box-shadow: 10px -10px black;}
    to {box-shadow: 10px -10px 10px white;}
}

@keyframes fall{
    from{left: 10px;}
    to{left: 200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fall{
    from{left: 10px;}
    to{left: 200px;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Responsive</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/smallfall.jpg" id="fall">
        <div class="circle" id="c1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem? seems to be working on here.

Comment: when I tested it on my computer the object I tried to animate becomes invisible until I remove the animation from the code.